# Do I need any server script to save() / fetch() Backbone model to localhost?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, localhost

Please, explain me the following thing, for I failed to find an answer so far and just don't get it.

The thing is that I've just started to learn Javascript client side on Backbone. I want to practice `model.save()` / `model.fetch()`, etc. Say, let's take some code like:

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
    urlRoot: "someUrl"
});
var model = new Model({'name': 'Peter'});
model.save();
```

Do I necessarily need any server-side script to save and fetch my model? Server-side is a completely new thing to me. Is there a way for me to try `model.save()` and `model.fetch()` and similar Backbone things on localhost without having to start learning php or things like that right now? I'm stuck at this point.

I hope somebody can give me a simple solution, like: Install this and that, do this and that, and now you can save, fetch, delete your backbone models on your localhost server and move further in your learning. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Jiri, I followed your advice with backbone-localstorage.js. It really enables me to save, fetch and destroy locally. Thank you so much. Though i haven't tried Backbone.Router this way. Hope it will enable me use it as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fortunately no! You do *not* need a backend server. Your backend can be the client. For example: the [`localStorage` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage).
And lucky you, you can use a localStorage plugin for Backbone like [Backbone.localStorage](https://github.com/jeromegn/Backbone.localStorage).

Another option you can use is [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) that also has its share of plugins like [this one](https://github.com/superfeedr/indexeddb-backbonejs-adapter).

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you Do need a back end server to perform operations like fetch(), and save() on your collections and models. A simple solution would be to set up a server based on node.js that have routes corresponding to these actions. Then, configure the node.js server to read from a json file that contains the sample data in json format for your application. So, when the server is started, the data in the json file is loaded in to the memory as a collection/model and then you may do save(), fetch() etc on the data in the memory

Comment: On surfing the web, I installed node.js, installed node static module in my directory and ran a test, showing me "server running on port 8080". But I don't get an idea what to do next. I'm still hoping to find a way to solve my problem and be able to practice backbone model.save()/fetch() before having to learn back end scripting. Though i doubt this. Which is worse, the choice is too big - php, .net, ruby... I can't make it up which way to go. If there is no other way than learning back end, then I'd appreciate advice on what to learn and the source you'd choose yourself. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Backbone.localStorage.js was the solution. Though it overrides backbone.sync, nevertheless it enables me to save/fetch/destroy models, use router, etc. As I presently cannot write server scripts myself, but want to practice using backbone, backbone.localstorage.js helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, after fully creating an app saving data on localstorage by backboneLocalstorage , I have to say that it limits backbone save and fetch functions. Well, backboneLocalstorage helped me learn backbone to some extend, and I made complete application working locally with its help. I used requirejs there as well.

But now I am learning Node.js. Well, I like to have a real server and database now, and there is no need in localstorage now.

So, if you have time and abilities to at the same time learn Backbone, Underscore, Requirejs, Node.js, Mongoose, Npm and lots of other stuff - better do this. If not, you may well start gradually from Backbone localstorage, and then move towards Node.js, server side and adopt your app to a real server.